# string.find() doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, stdstring

Hello guys I am trying to make an input-output AI and I am trying out some possibilities for the input so I am trying string.find(). But sometimes it doesn't work when I write sentences, probably because of the spaces. Could you take a look and tell me what's wrong or maybe just tell me what to use instead of string.find?()?

```
    std::string sentence;

std::cin >> sentence;

if (sentence.find("what") != std::string::npos)
{
    if (sentence.find("are") != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (sentence.find("you") != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (sentence.find("?") != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::cout << "I am an AI" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: "string.find() doesn't work properly" - `std::string::find` works just fine - if you know how to use it and use it on the correct data.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: And if you're actually using on what you think you're using it on.

Comment: Placing a `cout <<sentence;` after `cin >>sentence;` would have put you on a good path to solving this. First thing to do when debugging is gather information.

Comment: @user4581301 as would have using a debugger..

Comment: Can't argue with that, @Jesper . Well, I guess I could, but the argument would be something stupid like, "Debuggers are for the weak.  REAL men slam their head repeatedly against the wall for hours to prove their strength and perseverance."

Answer (score 4):

c++'s `cin` prompt grabs any characters until it finds a space, newline, or other delineating character. Try something like [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string sentence;
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
```